# Adding a glossary entry whose name is a macro that uses \equal{}

Tags: conditionals, glossaries

I have defined some commands that use `\equal{}` to test if an argument is empty or not. I would like to use these commands as names in a glossary. However, the following minimum example does not work when compiling with `latexmk`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\testWithEqual}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{Nothing}{Something}}
\newcommand{\testWithOutEqual}[0]{Anything}

\makeglossaries

% This entry works:
\newglossaryentry{testWithOutEqual}{
    name={\testWithOutEqual{}},
    description={testWithOutEqual entry}
}

% This entry results in failure:
\newglossaryentry{testWithEqual}{
    name={\testWithEqual{}},
    description={testWithEqual entry}
}    

\begin{document}

    \glsaddall
    \printglossary

\end{document}
```

In particular, I think the relevant message in the log is:

```
Undefined control sequence. <argument> \equal {}{}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define your own macro which tests for empty argument. The following does so and works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\testWithEqual}[1]{\MyIfEmptyTF{#1}{Nothing}{Something}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\MyIfEmptyTF[1]
  {%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
  }
\makeatother
\newcommand{\testWithOutEqual}[0]{Anything}

\makeglossaries

% This entry works:
\newglossaryentry{testWithOutEqual}{
    name={\testWithOutEqual{}},
    description={testWithOutEqual entry}
}

% This entry results in failure:
\newglossaryentry{testWithEqual}{
    name={\testWithEqual{}},
    description={testWithEqual entry}
}    

\begin{document}

    \glsaddall
    \printglossary

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. Would you be able to expand a little on why my previous empty-argument test (`\equal{#1}{}`) was insufficient?

Comment: @Adam because `\ifthenelse` and it's test are not expandable they might behave in unintended ways in expansion context. The test `\MyIfEmptyTF` is expandable and doesn't suffer from this problem. To see what I mean, try doing `\edef\foo{\MyIfEmptyTF{}{bar}{baz}}` and after that try doing `\edef\foo{\ifthenelse{equal{}{}}{bar}{baz}}`. The latter will suffer from the same problems as it does in `\newglossaryentry`.